# Azure Analysis Service Tabular Model connecting to Power BI Service .NetCore Database.Model is null exception

Tags: .net-core, powerbi, ssas-tabular, adomd.net, azure-function-async

In a Azure Function I have connect to the power bi service and can get a dataset by using the FindByName or GetByName but the Database.Model value is null.
Which means i cannot refresh the dataset or update anything.

While debugging can see all of the datasets in the workspace.
any help gratefully recevie. thanks

```
using (Server as_server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server())
{
    as_server.Connect(connectionString);
    Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Database db = as_server.Databases.FindByName(database);
    Model m = db.Model;
    //my model m is allways null pointless to go on
}
```

I am using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64 19.9.0.1-Preview and
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.NetCore.retail.amd64 19.9.0.1-Preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok i have also had the pain of trying to get this to work in .net core with little documentation, i have no idea why the below works but here is the code to get a tabular model

```
using (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server())
{
    server.Connect(connectionString);  
    Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database database = server.Databases.GetByName("adventureworks");
    Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Model  model = database.Model as Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Model;
}
```

note that `database.Model` is null when you inspect it and if you use it directly like
`database.Model.Tables` you get Object reference not set to an instance of an object for database.Model.get

however if you cast it, as i did in the last line of code suddenly is works!

Comment: I did not expect this to work but shockingly it did. I am using the .net framework version of these libraries as well.